# laravel highlight menu item of current page when using include header

Tags: jquery, css, laravel

I'm using @include for including header in all pages, but the problem is highlighting still on Home page item, how can I highlight the active page item
Example:
**The active css is current-menu-parent**

```
     <ul class="menu-list text-uppercase">
      <li class="current-menu-parent">
       <a href="{{url('/')}}" title="">Home</a>
        </li>
            <li>
               <a href="{{route('cdashboard')}}" class="btn_signin" title="">MY DASHBOARD</a>
       </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel/Blade can't do this by itself automatically.

You should check the current route name and if it's equal to the corresponding route, so add the `current-menu-parent` class to correspond `li`.

as a hint:

```
<li @if(Route::currentRouteName() === 'route_name') class="current-menu-parent" @endif>
```

**UPDATE:**

You can do it by Route-Path instead of Route-Name also:

```
<li @if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::is("/route_url")) class="current-menu-parent" @endif>
```

Comment: YaserKH Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i use this method 
my helper

```
function menuActive($route_name)
{
    return Route::currentRouteName() == $route_name ? 'active' : '';
}
```

uses

```
  <li class="{{menuActive('cdashboard')}}">
           <a href="{{route('cdashboard')}}" class="btn_signin" title="">MY DASHBOARD</a>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel/Blade can't do this by itself automatically.

You should check the current route name and if it's equal to the corresponding route, so add the current-menu-parent class to correspond li.

the edited code is

```
<ul class="menu-list text-uppercase">
<li @if(Route::currentRouteName() === 'route_name') class="current-menu-parent" @else class="class-name" @endif>
       <a href="{{url('/')}}" title="">Home</a>
        </li>
            <li>
               <a href="{{route('cdashboard')}}" class="btn_signin" title="">MY DASHBOARD</a>
       </li>
</ul>
```